# Eager load ONE from Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a many to many relationship for `users` and `roles`. A user can have multiple roles, but I only want `with` to grab the FIRST role.

Consider the following code:

```
User::with('roles')->get()
```

Works great for all roles, but I only want the first `role`.

I've set this up in my model but doesn't work:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->roles()->first();
}
```

How do I load `with` for only the first result?

Comment: What you mean by *doesn't work*, are you getting any error message, what behavior you observed. Also try changing its name to something else like, change from `public function role()` to `public function firstrole()`. If you are successfully getting all roles() then this should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `first` directly on the eager loaded relationship like this:

```
User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->first();
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`first()` actually executes the query and returns the results as a collection.  [Relationships must return a query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations), which can then be chained or executed, so using `first()` in a relationship won't work.

**UPDATE**

I realised you want to use `role` in `with`, so you need to create a relationship to do that.  Create a new relationship on your `User` model (you can use any [limit described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), not just `oldest()`):

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role')->oldest();
}
```

And then you can use it in with:

```
$users = User::with('role')->get();
```